# MongoTemplate.getCollectionNames and MongoTemplate,collectionExists method throws StringIndexOutOfBoundsException when connected to Azure Cosmos DB

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, azure-cosmosdb, spring-mongodb

I am trying to get the list of collections on a database. My application uses spring-boot 2.4.1 and Azure Cosmos DB. Below is the code block.

```
String uri= "mongodb://<username>:<password>@<hostname.documents.azure.com>:<port>/?ssl=true";
String dbName= "databaseName";
MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create(uri);
SimpleMongoClientDatabaseFactory mongoDbFactory  = 
                 new SimpleMongoClientDatabaseFactory(mongoClient, dbName);
MongoTemplate mongoTemplate = new MongoTemplate(mongoDbFactory);
System.out.println(mongoTemplate.getCollectionNames());
```

The code throws a very strange `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -4
    at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1931)
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.ListCollectionsOperation.projectFromFullNamespaceToCollectionName(ListCollectionsOperation.java:512)
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.ListCollectionsOperation.access$1500(ListCollectionsOperation.java:86)
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.ListCollectionsOperation$ProjectingBatchCursor.next(ListCollectionsOperation.java:418)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoBatchCursorAdapter.next(MongoBatchCursorAdapter.java:64)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoMappingCursor.next(MongoMappingCursor.java:48)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.lambda$getCollectionNames$28(MongoTemplate.java:2314)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.execute(MongoTemplate.java:535)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.getCollectionNames(MongoTemplate.java:2312)
    at TestApp.main(TestApp.java:20)
```

When I am connecting to a mongo instance that is running on my local with the connection string `"mongodb://localhost:27017"` the above code works fine.

And my relevant part of the `pom.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.1</version>
  </parent>
  <groupId>org.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>test-mongo</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

Any thoughts about this error?

Comment: Have you tried to get the collections using API Rest, to check if there is something strange https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/rest/api/cosmos-db/list-collections?

Comment: You can try the `mongoTemplate#executeCommand` - passing [listCollections](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/listCollections/) command to it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your connection uri correctness?

i cant see password part your uri

Add the password section uri like this

```
String uri= "mongodb://<username>:<password>@...
```

Comment: Question has been updated, password is being passed in. All methods/functions other than `getCollectionNames()` work fine.